# Logging Errors via WCF

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to learn about WCF. In order to do this, I thought I would build a error logging tool. This tool exposes a single WCF service. This service has a single operation called "LogError". LogError accepts three parameters: origin, message, and stackTrace. My method signature is shown here:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/LogException/{origin}/{message}/{stackTrace}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string LogException(string origin, string message, string stackTrace)
{
  // Save details to database
  return string.Empty;
}
```

Please note that I am learning WCF, so I'm not sure if I'm using a best practice here. However, because I'm writing to the database, I assumed a POST method would be best. From my understanding WebInvoke is best suited for POST methods. I want to use JSON because I want to call this from a variety of client applications and for it to be quick.

My question is, am I on the correct track and line of understanding so far? Can someone that understands WCF tell me if my line of thinking is correct thus far?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've written something similar:

```
    [WebHelp(Comment = "Add a log entry")]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddLogEntry", Method="POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    public void AddLogEntry(LogEntry entry)
    {
        WriteEntry(entry);
    }
```

But in my case I have a custom log object that I'm sending. The response format just tells the operation that it will be sending JSON back. I don't believe that it has any effect on what format of data it will accept.